# What is the name of the island?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth

What is the island at 2:31 into this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9tWh5uwQNY). I believe I've seen pictures of it before. It looks like a circle with a diameter of about 40 km. I'm curious to learn about the nature of the island.

> What is the name of the island?

Comment: Timothy, do you have a still photo of this island? So people willing to help you do not have to go through the video.

Comment: 1) You can include the timestamp in your YT link. 2) I see an island at 2:31, but it's nowhere near circular; it's long and skinny. Is this the correct video?

Answer (score 2):

This is [Viligili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villingili_(Gaafu_Alif_Atoll)), north of Kooddoo airport in the Gaafu Alif Atoll in the Maldives.

Coordinates: 00°45′25″N 73°26′10″E

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The audio track of the video clearly states:

> This is what it is like to go skydiving in the Maldives

So I would assume that the location is, in fact, the [Maldives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maldives)